# Stop WKWebView redirecting to another app based on Universal link

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, servicenow

We are using **WKWebview** to custom load and manage our ServiceNow instance, but however while login succeeds, if user has "ServiceNow" mobile app installed post login it opens ServiceNow app.

Tried blocking the final Url navigation action(**decidePolicyfor navigationAction**) without success.

It's happening due to Universal link at ServiceNow end. http://service-now.com/apple-app-site-association

Any ways to block this operation at our end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy(rawValue: WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow.rawValue + 2)!)
}
```

This seems to solve the issue.

Comment: the solution is working . will you please explain why it is working ???

Comment: This works because of this:
`static const WKNavigationActionPolicy WK_API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.11), ios(9.0)) _WKNavigationActionPolicyAllowWithoutTryingAppLink = (WKNavigationActionPolicy)(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow + 2);`
https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/995f6b1595611c934e742a4f3a9af2e678bc6b8d/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/WKNavigationDelegatePrivate.h#L61

It's a private navigation policy declared that skips the deeplinking. <Insert here generic warning that you should not use private APIs>

Answer (score 0):

hopefully WKWebView custom agent works for you. use following code

```
webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"
```